# JSP DCP's being included on page with wrong charset

Tags: encoding

I'm in the process of moving a portal from Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8. Everything seems to be working, except for JSP DCP's that are stored on the filesystem - they are put on the page with the wrong charset, which makes Norwegian characters (ÆØÅ) display wrongly:

[image: How it shouldn't look]

The DCP is being referenced with the following tag:

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation pageURI="tcm:52-139850-64" componentURI="tcm:52-213681" templateURI="tcm:52-213631-32"/>
```

When I open the JSP DCP on the server directly through VIM, the characters are correct, so the deployer seems to have the correct encoding.

Some notes:

- `jvm.xml` has `-Dfile.encoding` set to UTF-8.
- Just to be sure I also added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the startup parameters
- Other elements on the page are being displayed correctly, so the issue is not on the page level
- I am aware of this page http://elenaserghie.blogspot.no/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html but I can't draw a line to either of the levels.

Any ideas?

Comment: is your web.xml or page level setting  UTF-8 properly. also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047575/utf-8-but-still-not-showing-%C3%86%C3%98%C3%85-danish-chars

Comment: Yes, the issue is not on the page level as I stated in my question, as other UTF-8 encoded strings are being decoded correctly. Also, we have explicitly  defined all pages as UTF-8 in the JSP header: <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

Answer (score 2):

SDL Web 8 isn't the same as 2013 SP1 because of the Content Delivery microservices, hence the pointers from the blog post you mentioned aren't all applicable anymore.

The SDL Web 8 Deployer, should by default be setup with UTF-8 encoding, which would make sure that all file encodings are UTF-8. You should have the following Default Code page configured in `cd_storage_config.xml` of your Discovery service under `DeployerCapability` role node:

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost:8084/httpupload">
     <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
     <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
</Role>
```

What the actual Java file encoding is should still be possible to see in the debug logs, if those are any different than what is configured in the Discovery Service, then encoding issues will occur.